# angular-ui / ui-router nested states not inheriting custom data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

The method described for states to [inherit custom data from parent state](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-&-Nested-Views#inherited-custom-data) seems to not be working.

```
System = {
        name: 'System',
        url: '/System',
        controller: 'SystemHomeController',
        templateUrl: '/Content/html/SystemAdmin/Home.html',
        data: {
            level: "system"
        }
    },
    SystemAuditing = {
        name: "System.Auditing",
        url: "/Auditing",
        controller: 'AuditController',
        templateUrl: '/Content/html/Angular/Index.html',
        parent: 'System'
    };
$stateProvider
    .state(System)
    .state(SystemAuditing);
```

If I've understood what's at the link properly, when I'm at the child state, $state.current.data should contain the {level: "system"} within.  I've also tried setting the parent as an object, allowing it to be implied by the name, and defining the name through the call to $stateProvider.State(, ).  The home view includes the  tag and is rendering properly. But a console.log() from the child state's controller just doesn't show any of it there

```
{ 
"name": "System.Auditing", 
"url": "/Auditing", 
"controller": "TransferAuditController", 
"templateUrl": "/Content/html/Angular/Index.html", 
"parent": "System", 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inherited custom data just landed and is not part of the stable release. You'll have to build ui-router manually. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/master/README.md#developing

Comment: Thanks, it was driving me bonkers.